# Is it possible to assign different external IP addresses to different Docker containers running on the same server?

Tags: networking, docker

Let it be 3 machines on the network (192.168.1.1/24):

1. Server running Docker with 2 containers C1 and C2 (192.168.1.3)
2. Personal Computer 1 PC1 (192.168.1.4)
3. Personal Computer 2 PC2 (192.168.1.5)

C1 and C2 are serving a static website on tcp port 80 (C1) and 81 (C2) on the IP 192.168.1.3.

Is it possible to assign two different IPs to the containers?
Let's say for example 192.168.1.6:80 for C1 and 192.168.1.7:80 for C2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure.

```
docker run -p 192.168.1.6:80:80 --name C1 c1
docker run -p 192.168.1.7:80:80 --name C2 c2
```

You can bind a port to any IP configured on the host.

Comment: Thank you! Do I need multiple network interfaces (aka. cards) to configure multiple IPs to a single machine?

Comment: You can configure as many IP addresses as you want on a single physical NIC.

Comment: Do you happen to have a link or anything detailing the procedure to follow to configure multiple IPs on a Ubuntu machine?

Comment: [Sure, go ahead](https://www.google.com/search?q=ubuntu+20.04+multiple+ip+addresses+on+one+interface)